# keras: what is the difference between model.predict and model.predict_proba

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I found `model.predict` and `model.predict_proba` both give an identical 2D matrix representing probabilities at each categories for each row.

What is the difference of the two functions?

Answer (score 27):

**predict**

```
predict(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
```

Generates output predictions for the input samples, processing the samples in a batched way.

Arguments

```
x: the input data, as a Numpy array.
batch_size: integer.
verbose: verbosity mode, 0 or 1.
```

Returns

```
A Numpy array of predictions.
```

**predict_proba**

```
predict_proba(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

Generates class probability predictions for the input samples batch by batch.

Arguments

```
x: input data, as a Numpy array or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple inputs).
batch_size: integer.
verbose: verbosity mode, 0 or 1.
```

Returns

```
A Numpy array of probability predictions.
```

**Edit**: In the recent version of keras, predict and predict_proba is same i.e. both give probabilities. To get the class labels use predict_classes. The documentation is not updated. **(adapted from Avijit Dasgupta's comment)**

Comment: But it seems model.predict also gives a numpy array of prability predictions rather that direct samples labels

Comment: really! i don't think so. predictions not necessarily give you direct labels, it can give you score for labels, from which you find the best label but predict doesn't provide the class probabilities.

Comment: In the recent version of keras, predict and predict_proba is same i.e. both give probabilities. To get the class labels use predict_classes. The documentation is not updated.

Comment: `model.predict_proba` seems not to exist anymore in Keras 2.0.8.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in previous comments (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729210/4867185)), there currently isn't any difference.
However one seems to [exist only for backward compatibility](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2524#issuecomment-218590463) (not sure which one, and I'd be interested to know).

Answer (score 2):

Just a remark : In fact you have both `predict` and `predict_proba` in most classifiers (in Scikit for example). As already mentioned, the first one predicts the class, the second one provides probabilities for each class, classified in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent version of keras e.g. 2.6.0, predict and predict_proba is same i.e. both give probabilities. To get the class labels use predict_classes. The documentation is not updated