# Keras, output of model predict_proba

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

In the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods), the `predict_proba(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=1)` is

> Generates class probability predictions for the input samples batch by batch.

and returns

> A Numpy array of probability predictions.

Suppose my model is binary classification model, does the output is `[a, b]`, for `a` is probability of `class_0`, and `b` is the probability of `class_1`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here the situation is different and somehow misleading, especially when you are comparing `predict_proba` method to `sklearn` methods with the same name. In Keras (not sklearn wrappers) a method `predict_proba` is **exactly the same** as a `predict` method. You can even check it [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py):

```
def predict_proba(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=1):
        """Generates class probability predictions for the input samples
        batch by batch.
        # Arguments
            x: input data, as a Numpy array or list of Numpy arrays
                (if the model has multiple inputs).
            batch_size: integer.
            verbose: verbosity mode, 0 or 1.
        # Returns
            A Numpy array of probability predictions.
        """
        preds = self.predict(x, batch_size, verbose)
        if preds.min() < 0. or preds.max() > 1.:
            warnings.warn('Network returning invalid probability values. '
                          'The last layer might not normalize predictions '
                          'into probabilities '
                          '(like softmax or sigmoid would).')
        return preds
```

So - in a binary classification case - the output which you get depends on the design of your network:

- if the final output of your network is obtained by a single sigmoid output - then the output of `predict_proba` is simply a probability assigned to class 1.
- if the final output of your network is obtained by a two dimensional output to which you are applying a `softmax` function - then the output of `predict_proba` is a pair where `[a, b]` where `a = P(class(x) = 0)` and `b = P(class(x) = 1)`.

This second method is rarely used and there are some theorethical advantages of using the first method - but I wanted to inform you - just in case.

Comment: The answer is outdated

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you specify output of your model and your targets. It can be both. Usually when one is doing binary classification the output is a single value which is a probability of the positive prediction. One minus the output is probability of the negative prediction.