# Multiple predictions of multi-class image classification with Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I trained a `CNN` in Keras with images in a folder (two types of bees). I have a second folder with unlabeled `bees` images for prediction.

I'm able to predict a single image (as per below code).

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

test_image = image.load_img('data/test/20300.jpg')
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)

prob = classifier.predict_proba(test_image)
```

Result:

```
prob
Out[214]: array([[1., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I would like to be able to predict all of the images (around 300).

Is there a way to load and predict all the images in a batch? And will `predict()` be able to handle it, as it expects and array to predict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.predict_proba()` (which is a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41716380/712995) of `predict()` really) accepts the batch input. From the documentation:

> Generates class probability predictions for the input samples.
>   The input samples are processed batch by batch.

You just need to load several images and glue them together in a single numpy array. By expanding the 0 dimension your code already uses a batch of 1 in `test_image`. To complete the picture there's also a `Model.predict_on_batch()` method.

To load a batch of test images you can use `image.list_pictures` or `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` (which is compatible with `Model.predict_generator()` method, see the examples in the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)).