# Extract probability values for classification Keras when using validation_data

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I have a model and fit it using the following:

```
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs = epochs, verbose = 2, batch_size = 1000, shuffle = True, validation_data = (Xtest, ytest))
```

However, when using the built in validation_data option, I cannot find a way to extract the probability values and class assignments for the validation set.

I am thinking of implementing this with a callback, similar to the situation here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2548, but I am unsure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [predict_prob](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba)

You can also find the same question of this [stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/understanding-predict-proba-from-multioutputclassifier)

Comment: Would this give the exact same probabilities as what Keras computed immediately after training on that epoch? I could not find verification of this which is why I ask.

Comment: No. Please find the discussion here at -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716380/keras-output-of-model-predict-proba