# How to show the confidence of a prediction in a classifier in Python (Tensorflow 2.2/ Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.x

I have a problem with the prediction output. I leave attached the model code of my classifier (6 classes)
I'm using Tensorflow 2.2
The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow import keras
import cv2
import PIL
import os
import numpy as np

#Dir
train_dir ='/home/Tensorflow/Dataset_mix/train/'
validation_dir = '/home/Tensorflow/Dataset_mix/test/'

ACCURACY_THRESHOLD = 0.99
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}): 
        if(logs.get('accuracy') > ACCURACY_THRESHOLD):   
            print("\nReached %2.2f%% accuracy, so stopping training!!" %(ACCURACY_THRESHOLD*100))   
            self.model.stop_training = True

train_0_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, '0')  
train_1_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, '1')
train_2_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, '2')  
train_3_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, '3')  
train_4_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, '4')  
train_5_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, '5')  
validation_0_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, '0')  
validation_1_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, '1')  
validation_2_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, '2')  
validation_3_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, '3')  
validation_4_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, '4')  
validation_5_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, '5')  


num_0_tr = len(os.listdir(train_0_dir))
num_1_tr = len(os.listdir(train_1_dir))
num_2_tr = len(os.listdir(train_2_dir))
num_3_tr = len(os.listdir(train_3_dir))
num_4_tr = len(os.listdir(train_4_dir))
num_5_tr = len(os.listdir(train_5_dir))

num_0_val = len(os.listdir(validation_0_dir))
num_1_val = len(os.listdir(validation_1_dir))
num_2_val = len(os.listdir(validation_2_dir))
num_3_val = len(os.listdir(validation_3_dir))
num_4_val = len(os.listdir(validation_4_dir))
num_5_val = len(os.listdir(validation_5_dir))

total_train = num_0_tr + num_1_tr + num_2_tr + num_3_tr + num_4_tr + num_5_tr
total_val = num_0_val + num_1_val + num_2_val + num_3_val + num_4_val + num_5_val

batch_size = 32
epochs = 20
IMG_HEIGHT = 128
IMG_WIDTH = 128
callbacks = myCallback()
CLASS_NAMES = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, zoom_range=0.25, horizontal_flip=True, height_shift_range=.15, rotation_range=75, brightness_range=(0.25,0.9)) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           color_mode='grayscale',
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           classes = list(CLASS_NAMES))

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              color_mode='grayscale',
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),                                                              
                                                              classes = list(CLASS_NAMES))


model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,1)), #(W-F)/S +1 (128-3)/1 + 1 = 126  (32, 126, 126)
    Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu'), #(32, 124, 124)
    MaxPooling2D(), #(32, 62. 62)
    Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), #   (64, 60, 60)
    Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), #   (64, 58, 58)
    MaxPooling2D(),   #   (64, 26, 26)
    Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'), #   (128, 24, 24)
    Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'), #   (128, 22, 22)
    MaxPooling2D(),   #   (128, 11, 11)
    Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'), #   (256, 9, 9)
    Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'), #   (256, 7, 7)
    MaxPooling2D(),   #   (256, 3, 3)
    Flatten(),
    Dense(1152, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(1152, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(6, activation='softmax')

])

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()

history = model.fit(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_steps=total_val // batch_size,
    callbacks= callbacks,
    verbose=1
)

model.save('saved_model/ModelMix')
model.save('Modelmix.h5')
```

And for predict:

```
image_to_predict = cv2.imread('./image054.png')

image_to_predict = cv2.cvtColor(image_to_predict, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_to_predict = image_to_predict.reshape(1, 128, 128, 1)
print(image_to_predict.shape)

prediction = model.predict(image_to_precit)

print(prediction)
```

Well, when I do model.predict(image_to_predict) and I print the result, the output that comes back to me is the following:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

The output is correct, the detected class is the one expected but it is not what I want. I would need to have an output that would give me back the percentage of confidence with which the choice was made, so something like:

```
[[0.02 0.04 0.10 0.72 0.08 0.04]]
```

But I can't find any function that gives me the certainty of the evaluation.
Anyone have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747679/keras-what-is-the-difference-between-model-predict-and-model-predict-proba

Comment: Looking in the keras documentation I already tried using predict_proba() but the result is the same

Comment: The numbers you have are correct, those are the confidences produced by your model. Standard neural networks are generally overconfident, so you would need to use a Bayesian neural network to get more realistic confidences that truly represent model uncertainty. In the end it is not a programming problem, you need a different model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy you are of course right in principle, but it seems very likely that here what OP actually means is just the probabilistic predictions, and they have just used an incorrect terminology - notice that the elements of the probabilistic array they have posted as an example sum up to 1, as expected for a probabilistic prediction.

Comment: As implied by the comments above, it would seem that you are not actually looking for the confidence of the predictions but simply for the probabilistic predictions (as opposed to hard class ones). Please notice that **terminology matters**.

Comment: @desertnaut maybe I expressed myself badly, I'm not a great expert so I sin on terminology. I knowt that i don't have the prediction confidence but it is exactly what I am looking for and I do not know how to get it. What do you advise me to do? For now I am looking for the Bayesian neural network as suggested by Dr. Snoopy. Do you have any other suggestions to help me?

Comment: What I'm saying is just that what you have shown as required result, `[[0.02 0.04 0.10 0.72 0.08 0.04]]`, is not the prediction confidence - it's just the probabilistic prediction; and from your question, this is what you *seem* to be after, and not the confidence.

Comment: I really think predict proba is the right step. Have you tried a different image? Since you only stop training when  you reach an accuracy of more than 99%, your model may be really confident. Maybe try lowering that threshold to 80% and using predict proba on a different image?

Also I notice that in Python2, sometimes I have to specify that numbers are floats. Do you know if the code is automatically rounding the numbers?